# CSS drop down menu issue

Tags: html, css

I have created a CSS drop down menu at http://elankeeran.com/test/dropdown.html, but I am facing an on hover issue. Home tab is working fine. And I want to remove the width for `<ul id="menu" style="width:35px;">` any idea how to remove the width.

The "left Home" top border is missing as shown in the image below: 
[image]

How would I be able to fix this?

Comment: On a side note, you have `#menu { padddig:0px; }`. You should fix that. Also, you're using `id="menu"` twice. `id`s are supposed to be unique. You should switch to `class="menu"` and `.menu`.

Comment: thanks for information here I am doing for example so I copied the same UL tag. I will change to class

Answer (score 3):

The culprit is the `z-index:-1` in the `.dropdown_2columns` css. If you remove that, you get your borders back. Was there a reason you set the z-index to -1?

Comment: if i remove then It will look like a box border. But I want like "Home" tab

Comment: So basically what you are doing is hiding the overlapping portion of the border by moving it behind the #menu div, correct? In that case, you can get around that by changing the width set in the menu element from `138px` to `108px`, and removing the `margin-right:30px` from `#menu li`. But that would seem like a very hacky way of achieving that, I would start clean using meyer's css menu, and then add a `div` around the main `a` tag, which I'd use to hide the top part of the submenu border.

Comment: Thanks! top border issue somewhat OK but suppose tab content increase again top border miss aligned.... "left home" I am not able to select the listed drop down item when I hover the item its hiding... I dont know why?

Comment: I'd suspect that's because of the -1 z-index again. Like I said, you probably want to start fresh on the menus. There's a lot of code there that shouldn't be needed. But I guess you could work around it by removing the z-index on this, and putting a high z-index on the #menu.

Comment: No sorry, the high z-index won't work. I forgot the submenu is a child element of that element.

Answer (score -1):

If `width` is the only style applied, you can remove the entire `style` attribute by `$('#menu').removeAttr('style');`
Edited: oops, I don't know if you are using jQuery.

Comment: This would be a jQuery solution, not html or css.

Comment: That's right, I realized he didn't mention jQuery. It's being obvious for me that everybody is using jQuery :)

Comment: but i am looking for css html solution

Answer (score -2):

I think you can simply do:

```
delete document.getElementById("menu").style.width ;
```

Comment: Your answer makes no sense to me. Can you clarify it?

Comment: He wanted to know how to remove the property "width" so that it does not apply any more. That's how you remove a property in JS.

Comment: `delete document.getElementById("menu").style.width` will not work. To reset the CSS property `width` to its initial value, you want `document.getElementById("menu").style.width = 'auto'`.

Comment: won't deleting the property also have the same effect ? You solution is better though.

Comment: I am thinking to remove the width but your answer say how to apply the width.

Comment: [No.](http://jsfiddle.net/Gx7VA/) There's also the fact that this is tagged `html` and `css`, and no other JavaScript is being used on the page, so you should assume "no JavaScript".